# how to Receive two ajax json Data from .net

Tags: javascript, .net, json, ajax

i use .net and send js(ajax) two data to .net controller
in data test1 and test2 is json data.

```
.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/test/test_Put/",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {json_1:JSON.stringify(test1), json_2:JSON.stringify(test2)},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

.net controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult test_Put([FromBody]test1 tt1, [FromBody]test2 tt2){
        }
```

but i saw error ㅜㅜ
how should i handle it in .net

Comment: Well, the arguments to `test_Put` are named `tt1` and `tt2`, but you're passing `json_1` and `json_2`...

Comment: i know that problem but i can't find solution. tried a lot of a different ways but failed

Comment: You aren't sending the whole data as json but are setting contentType as json

Answer (score 0):

You should only have 1 [FromBody] in your action.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

> There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with
> [FromBody]. The ASP.NET Core MVC run-time delegates the responsibility
> of reading the request stream to the formatter. Once the request
> stream is read for a parameter, it's generally not possible to read
> the request stream again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.

Create a wrapper class for this instead.

```
public class TestRequest
{
    public test1 json_1;
    public test2 json_2;
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult test_Put([FromBody]TestRequest data){}
```

BTW, you should use camel case in your method and variable names.